# LaTeX Table with uncertainty from pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I am currently working on a report with many values and uncertainties calculated in python and stored in a pandas DataFrame.

These Values have to be put inside the report including the errors.
Currently my only way to do so, is to manually combine the values with the errors.
One example of this looks like the following:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \hline
    Konzentration $c/\si{\gram\per\liter}$ & $D_\text{app} / \si{\square\meter\per\second}$ & $R_h / \si{\meter}$ & PDI  \\
    \hline
    \SI{0.50}{} & \SI{9.9(2)e-13}{}  & \SI{3.84(8)e-7}{} & \SI{4.1(3)}{} \\
    \SI{0.33}{} & \SI{6.35(7)e-13}{} & \SI{5.96(6)e-7}{} & \SI{1.4(2)}{} \\
    \SI{0.25}{} & \SI{1.16(2)e-12}{} & \SI{3.26(6)e-7}{} & \SI{2.6(2)}{} \\
    \SI{0.20}{} & \SI{6.11(9)e-15}{} & \SI{6.20(9)e-7}{} & \SI{4.9(3)}{} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

I am aware of `pd.to_latex()` which partially decreased the amount of work but does as far is I know not work with erros.

Are you aware of any way on either LaTeX or python to achieve such a table without manually combining values and errors.
The DataFrame looks like the following:
[image]

The only idea I had so far, was to write a function which takes in the value, error and the size of the uncertainty (in this case always 1) and returns a string which I can use with `pd.to_latex()`.

Is there an easier or likely better way to do so?

Comment: Exporting the data from python as csv and importing it into latex with `svsimple` or `datatool` might be more flexible

Comment: Also have a look at `S` columns from siunitx instead of wrapping each cell entry in `\SI{}{}`, this will not only make writing simpler, but also allows to align the numbers

Answer (score 3):

I have written a function which combines the values and errors in a single string.

```
def conv2siunitx(val, err, err_points=1):
    val = f'{val:.20e}'.split('e')
    err = f'{err:.20e}'.split('e') 
    first_uncertain = int(val[1]) - int(err[1]) + err_points

    my_val = f'{np.round(float(val[0]), first_uncertain-1):.10f}'
    my_err = f'{np.round(float(err[0]), err_points-1):.10f}'.replace('.','')
    # Avoid 1. and write 1 instead
    if first_uncertain > 1:
        first_uncertain = first_uncertain + 1

    return(f'{my_val[:first_uncertain]}({my_err[:err_points]})e{val[1]}')
```

In combination with `S`-columns this leads to the result I was looking for.